# Как instagram распознает "не человеческую" активность

Tags: python, selenium, бот, instagram

Проблема такая использую selenium+python, после нескольких подписок на людей инстаграм блокирует активность на время "для" selenium (использую chromedriver),но в тоже время когда блокировка активна с обычного браузера которым я пользуюсь подписки работают. в коде использую рандомные задержки.

Comment: может из-за рандоманых задержек и не то? я имею в виду, нижняя граница задержки может быть слишком маленькой.

также может быть проблема в том, что мышка двигается не как у человека, при пользовании. моментально. вам не хочется использовать requests? наверняка эти запросы - обычные - post \ get - это можно легко симулировать с помощью requests

Comment: Через селениум удобнее парсить и отладку по началу делать т.к всё видно визуально в браузере. Сейчас инстаграм начал выдавать "подозрительную попытку входа", а после подтверждения авторизации по почте действия через селениум заблокированы, но в обычном браузере все работает как надо.